# Необходимо получить все DOM-елементы внутри iframe'a

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Есть внешний iframe внутри которого большая самостоятельная DOM-структура. Сам этот iframe находится внутри diva класс которому каждый раз новый по F5 генерирует серверная часть (до серверного кода доступа у меня нет)
Доступ до iframe я уже получил - допустим вот как на скрине главный родительский div внутри которого уже глубже на несколько уровней находится iframe у меня храниться в переменной **$iframe**
Задача пропарсить циклом всё это DOM-дерево вглубь iframe'a и

1. изменить в каждом элементе в котором есть innerText, этот innerText на условный '123'
2. предварительно положить в массив все те элементы(тэги) у которых есть innerText так, что бы я потом этот массив за JSON.stringify-ил и получить все эти элименты в формате {ключ: "значение"}

задача 1 наиболее приоритетна, спасибо.
[image: В первой рамке - главный div элемента, во 2ой iframe внутри которого уже находится DOM-дерево]

Comment: внешний айфрейм изменить без патчей браузера нельзя

Comment: А что значит внешний iframe? В src вроде относительный путь. Главное окно и iframe на одном домене?

Comment: Про особенности доступа к iframe см. https://learn.javascript.ru/cross-window-communication#dostup-k-soderzhimomu-ifreyma